# Why wont my JQuery Dialog Box work on Older Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

Here is the project's codepen link: http://codepen.io/Symbolistic/pen/Kgaqzp

Basically my issue is, the popup dialog which appears at the end, when the "followers" count is added completely.
It shows up perfectly fine on Desktop and on my Galaxy S7 Edge phone, but on my older phone (6 years old), I can't even click the button.

I used this same popup dialog code on my portfolio and the same issue applies there too. I can't click the link/button that activates that dialog, its just an unresponsive button basically.

My question is why is this happening and how can I fix this problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn").click(function(){
    clearData();    
    var instagram = $("#username").val();
    $.getJSON("https://gramgainer.com/search.php?username=" + instagram + "", function(data){
        var followers = commaSeparateNumber(data.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].user.followed_by.count);
        $(".user").append("<h4 class='userdata'>" + data.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].user.username+ "</h4>");
        $(".user").append("<img id='userpic' class='userdata' src='" + data.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].user.profile_pic_url_hd + "'height=100 width=100>");

        $(".posts").prepend("<h4 class='userdata'>" + data.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].user.media.count + "</h4>");
        $(".followers").prepend("<h4 class='userdata' id='curFollowers'>" + followers + "</h4>");
        $(".following").prepend("<h4 class='userdata' id='data'>" + data.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].user.follows.count + "</h4>");
        printPosts(data);
        $(".results").show();
        $(".images").show();
        $(".followNotification").prepend("<h4 class='userdata' id='notification' style='color:red;'>Adding Followers..</h4>");
        incFollowers(data);
        popUp();
    });
});

function printPosts(pics){
    var temp = pics.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].user.media.nodes;
    for(var i=0;i<pics.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].user.media.nodes.length;i++){
        $(".images").append("<img class='userpost col-xs-4 userdata' src='" + pics.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].user.media.nodes[i].thumbnail_src + "'height=300 width=180>");
    }
}

// Clear all Data on the page everytime the user clicks the button
function clearData(){
    $(".userdata").remove();
}

// Creates the increasing number effect
function incFollowers(info){
    // Animate the element's value from 400 to 400000:
    var temp = info.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].user.followed_by.count;
    var newTemp = temp+2500;
    var currency = $("#currency"); //[make sure this is a unique variable name]
    $({someValue: temp}).animate({someValue: newTemp}, {
    duration: 5000,
    easing:'swing', // can be anything

    step: function() { // called on every step
        // Update the element's text with rounded-up value: 
        $("#curFollowers").text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
        },

    done: function() {
        $("#notification").html("<h4 class='userdata' id='notification' style='color:red;'>DONE!</h4>");
        $('[data-popup=popup-1]').fadeIn(350);
    }
});
```

}

```
/**
* Format the number, so it will be seperated by comma
*/
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
    val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }
return val;
}


function popUp() {
    //----- Open
    $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e) {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //----- Close
    $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e) {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

});

Old Phone Information:
Model: HTC Inspire 4G
Android Version: 2.3.3
Browser version: WebKit/533.1

Comment: Could you be more specific with the model/os of the phone?

Comment: Sure
Model: HTC Inspire 4G
Android Version: 2.3.3
Browser version: WebKit/533.1